# How to click on a particular file in a web page whose filename is given on a text file using python-selenium

Tags: python, selenium, file, pytest, txt

I have gdrive testing named folder in my goggle drive inside which 4 files are there . So ,I have a webpage where automatically this files are saved but I have saved names of 3 files in a text file in my local . Now How can i click on only those files in a web page whose names is written on the text file.

testing_file = os.path.sep.join((TestBase.current_directory,'src','Cloudconnector_files' , 'files_to_test.txt'))
elem = Driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,'mat-checkbox-layout')
with open(check_file,'r') as f:
over = f.readlines()
for i in over:
res = i

```
    for x in Driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,'mat-checkbox-layout'):
        file_index = webdriver.ActionChains(Driver).move_to_element(x).click(res).perform()
    time.sleep(5)
```

```
Here , testing_file is the variable and files_to_test.txt is the file inside which the filenames are present which i want to click on a web page .

and class-name = mat-checkbox-layout is the locator of the small box near the filenames on the webpage where 4 files are present but out of this 4 boxes i only want to click 3 filename means 3 boxes not 4 boxes .
```

Expected : The filenames which is written on the .txt file that only files i want to click on a webpage

Comment: Can you post the URL and the whole code you've tried?

Comment: Soory , I cant share you the URL . Its not allowed to share anyone .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can **right click** on each file you want to click on using Selenium on the web page, then **click on inspect** and choose the HTML code for the files you want. Finally **right click** and **hover over "Copy"**, then select **"Copy selector"**(CSS Selector), so you'll use `By.CSS_SELECTOR` and `.click()`

Example:-

```
file1 = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'css_selector_example')
file1.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Helpful Ways to Locate Elements in Selenium

You can also locate an element using the `XPATH` in Selenium. You can look for the XPATH in Chrome using the following helpful tutorial https://www.browserstack.com/guide/find-element-by-xpath-in-selenium

```py
driver.find_element(By.ID, "id")
driver.find_element(By.NAME, "name")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "xpath")
driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "link text")
driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "partial link text")
driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "tag name")
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "class name")
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "css selector")
```

To learn more check out the official Python Selenium Documentation on Locating Elements: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

### Best Approach

So, I would suggest working with above provided options and use the best one in your scenario. From what I understand you can use `By.LINK_TEXT` or `By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEST` if the website you are working with has a particular naming structure to files if it embeds the download links in the HTML Source. Can your provide the URL or HTML Source to the Page so I can better help you. But the above options of finding elements should help you determine those elements where there is a text file.